# Is it possible to map an ienumerable to a bool using automapper?

Tags: c#, automapper

I would like to map an ienumerable to a bool using automapper. Is this possible, the bool would be true if items exist in the ienumerable and false otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [`Any()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx)?

```
Enumerable.Empty<string>().Any()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a mapping using [`Enumerable.Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337697.aspx) via

```
src => src.Sequence.Any()
```

where `src` is represents your source object and `Sequence` is a property on the source object that is an `IEnumerable<T>` for some `T`.